# How to return multiple values from table based on specific item that I entered?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I tried to use `Tooling_No_AfterUpdate()` for both Sub and Function but it prompt me 'Ambiguous name detected' as I know that I can't use the same identifier. Then, I changed the identifier and set it to public function but it doesn't work and prompt me 'User-defined type not defined'.

I'm creating a form for user to enter the tooling number to know the storage location where it can be more than one location. I tried to use `ADODB.Recordset` to get data from my asset table. So here's what I tried:

```
Private Function Tooling_No_Enter() As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Tooling_No_Enter = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("select FirstName, LastName from Employees")

End Function

Private Sub Tooling_No_AfterUpdate()
Dim strStorage_Location_1 As String
Dim strStorage_Location_2 As String
Dim strStorage_Location_3 As String
Dim strStorage_Location_4 As String
Dim strStorage_Location_5 As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = Tooling_No_Enter()
Do While Not rst.EOF
    strStorage_Location_1 = rst!Storage_Loacation_1
    strStorage_Location_2 = rst!Storage_Loacation_2
    strStorage_Location_3 = rst!Storage_Loacation_3
    strStorage_Location_4 = rst!Storage_Loacation_4
    strStorage_Location_5 = rst!Storage_Loacation_5
    Debug.Print strStorage_Location_1 + vbCrLf + strStorage_Location_2 + vbCrLf + strStorage_Location_3 + vbCrLf + strStorage_Location_4 + vbCrLf + strStorage_Location_5
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

After that, users able to choose the location while the chosen location will be recorded into asset table and transaction table and these are the parts i can't figure it out.

Comment: Can't make event procedure a Function. If you want to pass a recordset object to another procedure, one way is to declare the recordset variable in the module header then it will be available to any procedure in that module. If declared in a general module then it will be available to any other module. Looks like misspelling **Loacation_1**, etc.

Comment: Consider a combo or list box that lists locations associated with entered tooling number. This is called cascading combo/list box and very common topic. However, on second look, data appears to be non-normalized.

Comment: @June7 I see, I tried to move the code to module header but it prompt me that identifier cannot be found. What should I do?

Comment: Why are you looping through recordset and repeatedly setting variables? Only the last record data would be retrieved. Also, I don't see storage location fields in the recordset. Really can't make sense of any of this code.

Comment: @June7 I loop the recordset because i wanna search for the result. I don really know how this code work cause i just put in something that i learn from internet

Comment: Well, code is not 'searching', it would just loop and read, there is no selection criteria. But obviously the process isn't even getting that far because the code is just so bad. Can't advise a total fix because don't really understand what you want, don't know your data, don't know your business process. Again, how can you expect to reference storage fields when they aren't even in the recordset SQL statement? How does populating variables and printing them out to the Immediate window with Debug.Print help user? Does the answer give you any clue for path to proceed on?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method to open ADODB recordset. For one thing, Execute is used for action SQL (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT).

One way to use a recordset object in multiple procedures is to declare recordset variable in module header. Example shows declaring and setting and opening connection and recordset objects which are then referred to in another procedure not shown.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public strOldLabNum
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsOldSample As ADODB.Recordset
___________________________________________________

Private Sub cbxOldLabNum_AfterUpdate()

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rsOldSample = New ADODB.Recordset

strOldLabNum = Me.tbxOldYear & "A-" & Me.cbxOldLabNum

'select old sample info from table zSample
rsOldSample.Open "SELECT * FROM zSample WHERE LabNum='" & strOldLabNum & "';", _
    cn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic

End Sub
```